# arduino 4 digit 7-segment display hard to read

Tags: arduino, display

I was wondering if its possible to get the 4 digit 7 segment display showing the numbers more smoothly, cause sometimes its really hard to read it (harder then the image shows). Can I do something in my code? its a cheap display from china, is that why? Im using a shift register (74hc595n) together with the display. thanks for any replies :)

Picture of my 4 digit 7-segment display

[image]

my arduino code for displaying the numbers:

```
 void loop() {
  turnOnDigit(1);
  displayNumber(firstDigitReceived);
  delayMicroseconds(2000);
  turnOnDigit(2);
  displayNumber(secondDigitReceived);
  delayMicroseconds(2000);
  turnOnDigit(3);
  displayNumber(thirdDigitReceived);
  delayMicroseconds(2000);
  turnOnDigit(4);
  displayNumber(fourthDigitReceived);
  delayMicroseconds(2000);
 }


 int displayNumber(int number) {

 switch(number) {

case 0:
        updateShiftRegister(126);
break;

case 1:
       updateShiftRegister(48);                  
break;

case 2:           
        updateShiftRegister(109);         
break;

case 3:            
        updateShiftRegister(121);        
break;

case 4:         
        updateShiftRegister(51);           
break;

case 5:            
        updateShiftRegister(91);          
break;

case 6:

        updateShiftRegister(95);           
break;

case 7:           
        updateShiftRegister(112);          
break;

case 8:          
        updateShiftRegister(127);          
break;

case 9:
        updateShiftRegister(123);         
break;

}
}

void turnOnDigit(int digit) {
switch(digit){

case 1:
  digitalWrite(digit1, LOW);
  digitalWrite(digit2, HIGH);
  digitalWrite(digit3, HIGH);
  digitalWrite(digit4, HIGH); 
  digitalWrite(segP, LOW);
break;

case 2:
  digitalWrite(digit1, HIGH);
  digitalWrite(digit2, LOW);
  digitalWrite(digit3, HIGH);
  digitalWrite(digit4, HIGH);
  digitalWrite(segP, HIGH);
break;

case 3:
  digitalWrite(digit1, HIGH);
  digitalWrite(digit2, HIGH);
  digitalWrite(digit3, LOW);
  digitalWrite(digit4, HIGH);
  digitalWrite(segP, LOW);
break;

case 4:
  digitalWrite(digit1, HIGH);
  digitalWrite(digit2, HIGH);
  digitalWrite(digit3, HIGH);
  digitalWrite(digit4, LOW);
  digitalWrite(segP, LOW);
break;

}
}
```

NOTE: I've tried to change the delays, but it only gets worse with less microseconds

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is that you are changing digits and then updating your digit a few microseconds later.  So when you turn on each digit for a small time the last digit is showing there.  You should turn the digits off while you update your shift register and then turn on the digit you want to display.

Comment: Omg how did I not see that! Thank you! :D